# Is there an iOS app or jailbreak modification that can activate true caps lock?

Tags: keyboard, ios, jailbreak, caps-lock

I'm using jailbroken iOS 5.1.1 and am looking for an app or setting that enables true caps lock.  Meaning, once activated, caps lock behaves like it does on a PC and stays enabled when you switch to numbers or even between apps.

As it is right now, caps lock is disabled when you go to the home page, switch apps, or even switch to number input.

If necessary, I'm willing to manually configure a custom keyboard to have capital letters in place of the default ones.  I'm even willing to downgrade the operating system for this.

Does something like this exist in jailbreak land or is there a hidden setting of some sort?

Comment: Is it possible to add custom keyboards when jailbroken? If so, you might be able to get a custom keyboard that is the same as the regular one except the lowercase keys are capitalized, and use that as your "caps lock".

Comment: @asmeurer I looked into that, after iOS 3, there haven't been any good custom keyboard apps because Apple changed the way the keyboard works.  The best I could find only added a customizable fifth row.

Comment: To those that downvoted, if you think this question needs to be improved please edit it or leave a comment.

Answer (score -2):

To enable caps lock in iOS 5 double tap the shift key. The shift key will become blue signifying caps lock is enabled.

[image]

Caps lock will be disabled if switching to other input keyboards (switching to type numbers/special characters) or applications.

Source for answer is from a [TUAW](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/08/19/iphone-101-how-to-turn-caps-lock-on/) article.

Comment: -1 ... switching from app to app reverts to non-caps mode as the OP states "As it is right now, caps lock is disabled when you go to the home page, switch apps, or even switch to number input."